# Stream zip file without AllowSynchronousIO=true

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asynchronous

I am using **.NET Core 3.1**. I followed [this blog post](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2016/11/streaming-zip-on-aspnet-core.html) from Stephen Cleary to achieve .zip file streaming directly to client (without saving to memory first). I added a lot of comments so the code would be easier to understand.

**AttachmentsController.cs**

```cs
public IActionResult DownloadAll(int commentId)
{
    var syncIOFeature = HttpContext.Features.Get<IHttpBodyControlFeature>();
    if (syncIOFeature != null)
    {
        syncIOFeature.AllowSynchronousIO = true; // DOESN'T WORK IF I REMOVE THIS
    }

    List<Attachment> attachments = _attachmentsService.GetAll(commentId);

    return new FileCallbackResult(new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream"), async (outputStream, _) =>
    {
        using (var zipArchive = new ZipArchive(outputStream, ZipArchiveMode.Create))
        {
            foreach (Attachment attachment in attachments)
            {
                var zipEntry = zipArchive.CreateEntry(attachment.FileName));
                using (var zipStream = zipEntry.Open())
                {
                    using (var transaction = _dbContext.Database.BeginTransaction())
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            using (var stream = _dbContext.GetLargeObjectStream(attachment.Id))
                            {
                                await stream.CopyToAsync(zipStream);
                            }

                            transaction.Commit();
                        }
                        catch
                        {
                            transaction.Rollback();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    })
    {
        FileDownloadName = "Attachments.zip"
    };
}
```

**FileCallbackResult.cs**

```cs
/// <summary>
/// Represents an <see cref="ActionResult"/> that when executed will
/// execute a callback to write the file content out as a stream.
/// </summary>
public class FileCallbackResult : FileResult
{
    private Func<Stream, ActionContext, Task> _callback;

    /// <summary>
    /// Creates a new <see cref="FileCallbackResult"/> instance.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="contentType">The Content-Type header of the response.</param>
    /// <param name="callback">The stream with the file.</param>
    public FileCallbackResult(string contentType, Func<Stream, ActionContext, Task> callback)
        : this(MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse(contentType), callback)
    { }

    /// <summary>
    /// Creates a new <see cref="FileCallbackResult"/> instance.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="contentType">The Content-Type header of the response.</param>
    /// <param name="callback">The stream with the file.</param>
    public FileCallbackResult(MediaTypeHeaderValue contentType, Func<Stream, ActionContext, Task> callback)
        : base(contentType?.ToString())
    {
        Callback = callback ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(callback));
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the callback responsible for writing the file content to the output stream.
    /// </summary>
    public Func<Stream, ActionContext, Task> Callback
    {
        get
        {
            return _callback;
        }
        set
        {
            _callback = value ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(value));
        }
    }

    /// <inheritdoc />
    public override Task ExecuteResultAsync(ActionContext context)
    {
        if (context == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(context));

        var executor = new FileCallbackResultExecutor(context.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<ILoggerFactory>());
        return executor.ExecuteAsync(context, this);
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// An action result handler of type file
/// </summary>
internal sealed class FileCallbackResultExecutor : FileResultExecutorBase
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Creating an instance of a class <see cref="FileCallbackResultExecutor"/>
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="loggerFactory"></param>
    public FileCallbackResultExecutor(ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
        : base(CreateLogger<FileCallbackResultExecutor>(loggerFactory))
    { }

    /// <summary>
    /// Handler execution
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="context">Action context</param>
    /// <param name="result">Action result</param>
    /// <returns><see cref="Task"/></returns>
    public Task ExecuteAsync(ActionContext context, FileCallbackResult result)
    {
        SetHeadersAndLog(context, result, null, result.EnableRangeProcessing);
        return result.Callback(context.HttpContext.Response.Body, context);
    }
}
```

How can I make it work without setting `syncIOFeature.AllowSynchronousIO = true`? I assume that this line makes the code run slower? I noticed that downloading zip is about 4 times slower than downloading just one file without zipping it.

Comment: You'll probably want to follow this issue :) https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/1541

Comment: Is there any workaround for now until they implement this?

Comment: I'm not aware of any at least :|

Comment: Can `AllowSynchronousIO = true` be the reason for slower download speed?

Comment: What is the size of the file? I don't think that allowing synchronous IO can have such a performance impact, but zipping (especially a big file) can. What are the metrics if you use a Stopwatch to calculate the duration for both zipping and just returning the raw file? (both read from the database of course)

Comment: If I download a single file (without zipping), download speed is about 30MB/s. When I download it as a zip file, download speed is ~13MB/s. The file size is 400MB. Do you think zipping big file is bottleneck here?

Comment: Of course it is. The output stream can be feeded 13 MB per second as it seems, when using zipping. Do you "have to" zip the file? I think the web server will serve the file using gzip or deflate (if specified by the client) even if you don't compress it yourself. In this case, it is probably trying to re-compress it which will also not produce a smaller size.

Comment: You are right, when I specified `CompressionLevel.NoCompression` the download speed increased to 30MB/s. Thank you!

Comment: Oh, so the bottleneck was the re-compression ?

Comment: What do you mean by recompression? I want to return multiple files to the client at once. Hence, I zipped them and sent them to the client as one .zip file.

Comment: By recompression I mean the gzip or deflate done by the web server, but never mind. I think your question of whether allowing sync IO would cause the slow download speed has resolved.

Comment: Out of curiosity, you will still be doing the zipping (with Compression) right? Because despite causing 13MB/s download speed, the content size to be downloaded would decrease significantly and it will still be beneficial?

Comment: Yes, I will still do the compression to reduce final zip file size.